# Proof of Goursat's theorem without using contradiction

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, line-integrals, holomorphic-functions

In Tao's [Notes 3 on complex analysis](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0irGJ6bTWAhWGmBoKHWvXB_kQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fterrytao.wordpress.com%2F2016%2F10%2F02%2Fmath-246a-notes-3-cauchys-theorem-and-its-consequences%2F&usg=AFQjCNHF_czUPp24bceIojlLgFX6rwR4Mw) there is the following Exercise (number 10)

> Find a proof of Goursat's theorem that avoids explicit use of proof by contradiction.

Goursat's theorem states that $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open, $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $\Delta \subset U$ is a solid triangle then the complex line integral
$$\int_{\partial \Delta} f(z) \,\mathrm{d} z$$
vanishes.

A Hint ist given:

> Use the fact that a solid triangle is compact, in the sense that every open cover has a finite subcover.

I can find multiple proofs without explicit use of contradiction if I assume that the derivative $f'$ is continuous (that is, if $\forall \varepsilon > 0: |x| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow x = 0$ doesn't use contradiction).

Any ideas on how to prove it without using the continuity of the derivative?

Comment: Could you give the URL of Terence Tao's notes you cite ?

Comment: A proof of Goursat's theorem without assuming the continuity of $f^{\prime}$ can be found in R. Churchill and J.W. Brown's Complex Variables and Applications. However, that statement of the theorem on Tao's page looks a little different than the one I learned (such as the part regarding the convex hull of a triangle).